# StreamWriter loses string characters when writing to file

Tags: c#, character, streamwriter

Certain circumstances have forced me to write own simple logger. Method for writing entries into file runs in a separate thread and looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;    

private ConcurrentQueue<Event> OccuredEvents { get; }

private void Work()
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream (filename, FileMode.Append, 
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            while (OccuredEvents.TryDequeue(out Event currentEvent))
            {
                 writer.WriteLine(currentEvent.ToString());
                 writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes in files appears some enries like that:

```
27.12.2018 08:49:13 [3e2291e2-a489-45ed-b169-fcc6b7bd1eda] [INFO] AcceptCallback - Client accepted (172.23.64.31:49820)
:49:13 [3e2291e2-a489-45ed-b169-fcc6b7bd1eda] [INFO] GenerateResponse - AliveCommand | Data | AccountName: DOMAIN_KVC\07221147
```

or:

```
27.12.2018 08:49:13 [3e2291e2-a489-45ed-b169-fcc6b7bd1eda] [INFO] GenerateResponse - AliveCommand | Data | A27.12.2018 08:49:13 [3e2291e2-a489-45ed-b169-fcc6b7bd1eda] [INFO] AcceptCallback - Client accepted (172.23.7.86:49593)
```

As seen, part of entry are lost or overlay another. Appearance of such anomalies is dependent on the number of entries. Apps with intense logging produce most of this "stubs".

What is my mistake? How to force StreamWriter to write full string into file?

Comment: Where is `Work()` being called from? Is it a single thread? Are multiple applications writing to the file at the same time?

Comment: why are you flushing everytime after writing ?

Comment: This doesn't really look thread safe (even though we cant see the pertinent code) , i would hazard a guess if you changed your `FileShare.ReadWrite` to `FileShare.Read` you will get access errors due to 2 threads trying to get exclusive write access to the same file handle

Comment: remove `writer.Flush();` you don't need if you using the keyword `using`

Comment: @John, Work() is called in single thread. In that situation, file used only by one instance of application.

Comment: @mkjh, its reduce amount of "stubs" in practice. But it's wrong, i know.

Comment: @Bad If `Work()` is only run from a single thread in a single application, I don't see how what you have described could happen. I recommend making the change @TheGeneral suggested and then see if you get any exceptions.

Comment: @TheGeneral, thats true, but only one thread in that situation is used.

Comment: Can you show the code calling Work? And the code creating the thread where it is called?

Comment: The only way I can reproduce a similar scenario is by running `Work()` from multiple threads.

Comment: @TheGeneral, you was right. I got a lot of access exceptions. Mistake was in my calling code. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

@TheGeneral was right. I've got a lot of access exceptions. Mistake was in my calling code (several threads was created instead of one). Thanx all for help!